# How to play animated gif in android jdk besides extract into static images?

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to play animated gif directly in android jdk now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me. I think there is no way. Android 2.0 doesn't support gif's for surely. I don't know if 2.2 supports or not.

You can use animation for doing simple things.

Answer (score 0):

Ther is no such a way, sorry. You still have to do that by hands.